# Codename One - Share a video from a CN1 app to another app

Tags: codenameone

How can I share a video recorded with Codename One with the native OS sharing support? The ShareButton supports only text and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo can use Display.getInstance().share(String text, String path, String type), where text is the string to share in your case video file, path is file path to your video file, type is type of the video(i.e mimetype).

Comment: Is the Javadoc incorrect? It explicitly refers only to images: `public void share(String text, String image, String mimeType)`

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani its correct, its just you need to set correct mimetype and path

Comment: The API was originally designed with the image use case but videos should work